# SDK 25.1.1 NPE: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.view.View.getVisibility()' on a null object reference

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-support-library

My code as below, where my Fragment would `popBackStackImmediate` when the `fragmentEmpty` resurface. All works well in Support SDK from 25.1.0 and before.

```
class FragmentEmpty : Fragment() {

    var fragmentTwo : Fragment? = null
    var fragmentOne : Fragment? = null

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_empty, container, false)
    }


    override fun onViewCreated(view: View?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        if (childFragmentManager.findFragmentByTag("FragmentOne") == null) {
            fragmentOne = FragmentOne()
            childFragmentManager.beginTransaction().add(R.id.container, fragmentOne, "FragmentOne").commit()
        } else {
            fragmentOne = childFragmentManager.findFragmentByTag("FragmentOne")
        }

        if (childFragmentManager.findFragmentByTag("FragmentTwo") != null) {
            fragmentTwo = childFragmentManager.findFragmentByTag("FragmentTwo")
            childFragmentManager.popBackStackImmediate()
        } else {
            fragmentTwo = FragmentTwo()
        }

        val transitionInflater = TransitionInflater.from(activity)
        val sharedElement = transitionInflater.inflateTransition(R.transition.shared_transition)
        fragmentTwo?.sharedElementReturnTransition = sharedElement
        fragmentOne?.sharedElementEnterTransition = sharedElement
    }

    fun openFragmentTwo() {
        var fragmentTransaction = childFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
        fragmentTransaction = fragmentTransaction.addSharedElement(activity.findViewById(R.id.fragment_button), "my_transition")
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container, fragmentTwo, "FragmentTwo").addToBackStack("").commit()
    }

}
```

When move to 25.1.1 and later e.g. 25.2.0. and even 25.3.0, I now have this error when `popBackStackImmediate`

```
 java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.view.View.getVisibility()' on a null object reference
     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransitionCompat21.findNamedViews(FragmentTransitionCompat21.java:387)
     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransition.captureOutSharedElements(FragmentTransition.java:693)
     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransition.configureSharedElementsUnoptimized(FragmentTransition.java:605)
     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransition.configureTransitionsUnoptimized(FragmentTransition.java:300)
     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransition.startTransitions(FragmentTransition.java:113)
     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2146)
     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.optimizeAndExecuteOps(FragmentManager.java:2103)
     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.popBackStackImmediate(FragmentManager.java:823)
     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.popBackStackImmediate(FragmentManager.java:776)
     at myproject.com.myapplication.FragmentEmpty.onViewCreated(FragmentEmpty.kt:32)
     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1314)
     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1528)
     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1595)
     at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.executePopOps(BackStackRecord.java:807)
     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(FragmentManager.java:2360)
     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2149)
     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.optimizeAndExecuteOps(FragmentManager.java:2103)
     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.popBackStackImmediate(FragmentManager.java:823)
     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.popBackStackImmediate(FragmentManager.java:776)
     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onBackPressed(FragmentActivity.java:178)
```

There's this link stating it will be fix
https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=234324&sort=-id&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Sta

However it hasn't been fix. I wonder if there's a workaround for this issue, while waiting for the fix, other than stay in 25.1.0?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research into the Fragment of pre 25.1.0 and post 25.1.0, the main different that cause the flow to be different is setting the default AllowOptimization is turn from `true` to `false`.

To get back the 25.1.0 behavior when using later version of SDK, one could set `setAllowOptimization(true)` on the fragmentTransaction.

```
    fun openFragmentTwo() {
        var fragmentTransaction = childFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
        fragmentTransaction = fragmentTransaction.setAllowOptimization(true).addSharedElement(activity.findViewById(R.id.fragment_button), "my_transition")
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container, fragmentTwo, "FragmentTwo").addToBackStack("").commit()
    }
```

This will solve the Crash.